# Identifying if a string ONLY has specific text

Tags: python

I have a column with a string that sometimes has one name, two, names or several names separated by semi-colons. I want to identify if a row matches all the specified names, but not if a row contains only some of the specified names.

SME

Row 1 - John;Ralph;Susan;Joe

Row 2 - Ralph

Row 3 - Susan;Ralph;Robert;Margaret

Row 4 - Ralph;Susan

```
df1['SME'] = df1.SMES.str.ONLY contains('Ralph', na=False, case=True) 
df2['SME'] = df1.SMES.str.ONLY contains('Ralph;Susan', na=False, case=True)
```

Expecting df1

Row 1 - False

Row 2 - True

Row 3 - False

Row 4 - False

Expecting df2

Row 1 - False

Row 2 - False

Row 3 - False

Row 4 - True

Comment: Did you try df1[df1['SME'] =='Ralph']?

Comment: "only contains" is the same as "equals", yes?

Comment: In your second example would you expect it to also match Susan;Ralph on line 4 as well? In other words, does order match? I think you are wanting to know when a given line contains all the specified names and only the specified names but the order of the names doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to flag Susan;Ralph as well

Answer (score 0):

To check for an exact value you can put a condition inside your df like so :

```
df1[df1['SME'] == 'Ralph']
```

If you only want to have the true/false values, you can create a mask just with the condition :

```
mask = df1['SME'] == 'Ralph'
```

Answer (score 0):

make some lambda functions:

```
f1 = lambda x: True if 'Ralph' in x else False
```

so you will the .apply to make a new column.

```
df['has_Ralph'] = df['SME'].apply(f1)
```

so yu can select these columns:

```
df_Ralph = df[df['SME'] == True]
```

Comment: getting following error when .apply(f1)  TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Comment: but how is the type of data that do you have in the column "SME" if is boolean so is this. the function lambda f1 is for use in a column that has only strings. you can change True and False for 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found an online python editor: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

```
Row1 = "John;Ralph;Susan;Joe"
Row2 = "Ralph"
Row3 = "Susan;Ralph;Robert;Margaret"
Row4 = "Ralph;Susan"

Find1 = "Ralph"
Find2 = "Ralph;Susan"
Find3 = "Susan;Ralph"

def ContainsAllOf(Row,Find):
    Result = 'False'
    Rows = Row.split(';')
    Finds = Find.split(';')
    if len(Rows) == len(Finds):
        difference = [r for r in Rows if r not in Finds]
        if len(difference) == 0:
            Result = 'True'
    print(Row + '\n' + Find + '\n' + Result + '\n')

ContainsAllOf(Row1,Find1)
ContainsAllOf(Row2,Find1)
ContainsAllOf(Row3,Find1)
ContainsAllOf(Row4,Find1)

ContainsAllOf(Row1,Find2)
ContainsAllOf(Row2,Find2)
ContainsAllOf(Row3,Find2)
ContainsAllOf(Row4,Find2)

ContainsAllOf(Row1,Find3)
ContainsAllOf(Row2,Find3)
ContainsAllOf(Row3,Find3)
ContainsAllOf(Row4,Find3)
```

Here's the output:

```
John;Ralph;Susan;Joe                                                                    
Ralph                                                                                   
False                                                                                   

Ralph                                                                                   
Ralph                                                                                   
True                                                                                    

Susan;Ralph;Robert;Margaret                                                             
Ralph                                                                                   
False                                                                                   

Ralph;Susan                                                                             
Ralph                                                                                   
False                                                                                   

John;Ralph;Susan;Joe                                                                    
Ralph;Susan                                                                             
False                                                                                   

Ralph                                                                                   
Ralph;Susan                                                                             
False                                                                                   

Susan;Ralph;Robert;Margaret                                                             
Ralph;Susan                                                                             
False                                                                                   

Ralph;Susan                                                                             
Ralph;Susan                                                                             
True                                                                                    

John;Ralph;Susan;Joe                                                                    
Susan;Ralph                                                                             
False                                                                                   

Ralph                                                                                   
Susan;Ralph                                                                             
False                                                                                   

Susan;Ralph;Robert;Margaret                                                             
Susan;Ralph                                                                             
False                                                                                   

Ralph;Susan                                                                             
Susan;Ralph                                                                             
True
```